# Calculating log-likelihood from transformed Rician noise

Tags: python, likelihood

I have data which has additive Rician noise. I found that the likelihood function for the Rice distribution in equation 2.3 here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5065.pdf

For my analysis, however, we take a signal (a vector of N points) that has Rician noise, and then we transform it in the following way (given in Python code, but let me know if someone would like me to write it out):

```
def convert(S, C1, C2, C3, C4):
        

   A=S/np.mean(S[0:5])

   E0 = exp(-C1*C2)

   E = (1.0 - A + A*E0 - E0*np.cos(C3)) / (1.0 - A*cos(C3) + A*E0*np.cos(C3) - E0*np.cos(C3))

   R = (-1/C2)*np.log(E)
 
   transformed_signal = (R-C1)/C4

   return transformed_signal
```

Where C1-C4 are known constants. The first 5 points used here are the baseline of the signal (before it changes). The total number of points in signal is ~1000. I then fit this transformed_signal to a model to extract 2 parameters of interest. My question is how do I calculate the likelihood function for this transformed data? Does anyone know the procedure to achieve that?

Comment: Some key words seem to be missing: what should appear between "known" and "Where"?  Regardless, your presentation of the situation appears overly complicated, because in effect $E$ is a rational transformation of $S$ (a linear function divided by another one). Simplifying that will go a long way towards answering your question, because the only step left to do would be to compute its derivative. The mean of `S[0:5]` could be a complication, but it's ambiguous: exactly how long is `S` and how would this procedure generalize to signals of other lengths?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I cleaned it up. Signal is about 1000 time points, the first 5 points are estimated to be the baseline (before the signal changes due to an infusion). Can you expand upon "the only step left to do would be to compute its derivative"? Why do I need to calculate the derivative, is that part of the procedure to calculate the likihood function? Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Might I recommend either not dividing by a baseline or using an entirely different procedure?  What you're doing is a *huge* complication that makes it virtually impossible to express a likelihood.  Consider fitting the raw signal and then adjusting the *fit* to compute estimates of the parameters of interest.

Comment: Hello, interesting idea. I am dividing by the baseline because that is what is required to convert my signal into physical units, which the model I then fit to requires. What is an entirely different procedure I could use to extract the parameters of interest? What if I were able to assume that the mean(S[0:5]) was a "known constant"? In essence, I can measure the baseline for very long so I could know S very precisely. Does that simplify things at all? I want to calculate the log-likelihood so I can then maximize it to obtain a set of parameters. That's what I'm really after

Comment: It would be dangerous to assume just half a dozen observations are a "known constant."  In effect, any statistical error inherent in those few observations gets propagated into *your entire adjusted signal,* inducing potentially an enormous amount of serial correlation and likely greatly degrading its analysis.  Instead, if you use maximum likelihood to fit the parameters to the raw signal, you can compute any derived parameter you like from its estimates.

Comment: Hello whuber, thank you for your response. I will have to think about how to fit the raw signal, it's not intuitively obvious to me. That convert function converts a raw arbitrary unit signal into a concentration curve (I left those details out). Such concentration curves are required by the model. Anyways, I am able to measure the baseline signal for a very long time, so I can know it very preiclsey. If we did treat mean(S[0:5]) as a known constant, do you know how I would proceed in calculating the likelihood function to extract my desired parameters? I

Comment: Hello Whuber, I figured it out. Your comments were extremely helpful, thank you very much!